# parabolic equation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i want to calculate a parabola.i know the first speed vector v `(vx,vy)`, first position `(0,0)`,just considering gravity (`g=-9.8`).

```
y=a*x^x+b*x+c
```

could someone help me to calculate a,b,c expressions with (vx,vy,g).

my result is:

```
a=g/(2*vx*vx);
b=vy/vx;
c=0
```

i don't know it's right or not.it seems to be right in topright quadrant(x>0,y>0), seems to be wrong in other three quadrant.

could someone help me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does this have to do with [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1dkin/u1l6a.cfm]

So: `x = vx*t + .5*0*t**2` and `y = vy*t - .5*9.8*t**2`

You can plug those into [the graphinator](http://www.nmichaels.org/graph/graphinator.py) and you'll end up with a line for x and a nice parabola for y.